# In Python: When L is a list and I assign L=L.appened(x) (for some object x), why do I get a None object?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am a beginner to programming and was working in a for loop and realised the error I was getting is because of the reason in the title. Why Does the happen anyway? Is this a general property of mutable ojects?.

T

Comment: `help(list.append)` shows `append(...) L.append(object) -> None -- append object to end`. Functions that mutate objects don't normally also return the object. But in the end, its just doing what its documented to do.

Answer (score 0):

`append` modifies the list in place. There is no need to do `L=L.append(x)`; Simply running `L.append(x)` should suffice. The reason L is being set to none in your code is because there is no return value for append